# Apollo server GraphQL network issue

Tags: javascript, express, graphql, apollo

I am experiencing a problem. I searched and tried everything. It is about a networking issue I think or a bug in GraphQL(Apollo-Server-Express). I am sending a query that seems to be perfectly correct and fine, tested the values and they are all good. I send the request and it shows a 200 status code, it shows the content to be correct. However, the problem arises when I open the networking window in the dev tools. It gives me an error that the value expected is a String but it received undefined. Even when it's clearly visible even in the request payload. I did check the schema and it seems correct. Now I have no idea why it does that. Actually, I receive the data inside the resolver but all of it is in a single variable(password) as an object while the other variable(email) is undefined. I have no middleware that can hurt incoming requests.

Client-side query:

```js
signIn: (email: string, password: string) => requests.post({query: `
    query ($email: String!, $password: String!) {
        signIn(email: $email, password: $password) {
            _id
            name
            email
            avatar
            admin
            rents{
                _id
            }
            createdAt
            updatedAt
          }
        }
    `, variables: {
        email: email,
        password: password,
    }}),
```

[Network panel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1hf7.png)

[Request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGflP.png)

[Schema query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd90U.png)

[Resolver and return outcome when executing the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqyWr.png)

Comment: just bad resolver [args definition], read docs! test it (API) in playground before coding FE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `signIn` function is broken. It does not receive `email` and `password` as the first two arguments, as your method has declared them. Like every resolver function, the first parameter is the parent object (the root object in case of `Query` fields) and the second parameter is **an object of arguments**.

The output of the log statements in your server code should have made this obvious.

To fix your code, use

```
const Query = {
    async signIn(_root, args, _context) {
//                      ^^^^
        const { email, password } = args;
        …
    }
};
```

or

```
const Query = {
    async signIn(_root, {email, password}, _context) {
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        …
    }
};
```